# Azure API delimiter is not supported but required function argument?

Tags: azure, go

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad

I am looking at the Azure ListBlobs API page where its delimiter is definitely supported. My code is the following

```
    pager := client.NewListBlobsHierarchyPager("/", &container.ListBlobsHierarchyOptions{
    })

    keys := make([]string, 0)
    for pager.More() {
        res, err := pager.NextPage(ctx)
        HandleError(err)
        for _, val := range res.Segment.BlobItems {
            keys = append(keys, *val.Name)
        }
    }
```

Yet I still get the following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>UnsupportedQueryParameter</Code><Message>One of the query parameters specified in the request URI is not supported.
RequestId:bdcdc245-001e-00a5-534c-0c0387000000
Time:2023-10-31T22:50:32.4761465Z</Message><QueryParameterName>delimiter</QueryParameterName></Error>
```

How can this not be supported when it is a required argument? I have tried various other delimiters as well including an empty string

Answer (score 0):

The Azure ListBlobs API page contains [this remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad#snapshots-in-the-response):

> ## Snapshots in the response
>
> Snapshots are listed in the response only if the `include=snapshots` parameter was specified on the URI. Snapshots listed in the response don't include the `LeaseStatus` element, because snapshots can't have active leases.
>
> Using service version 2021-06-08 and above, you can call `List Blobs` with a delimiter and include snapshots in the enumeration. **For service versions prior to 2021-06-08, a request that includes both returns an InvalidQueryParameter error (HTTP status code 400 – Bad Request)**.

Looks like you're using a service version prior to 2021-06-08 and setting the `container.ListBlobsHierarchyOptions` like this:

```golang
&container.ListBlobsHierarchyOptions{
    Include: container.ListBlobsInclude{
        Snapshots: true,
    },
}
```

See also the change log for [Version 2021-06-08](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/version-2021-06-08):

- ...
- The ability to call List Blobs with delimiter and include snaphots in the enumeration.